# Based on start date and end date how to get financial years using php?

Tags: php

Financial years starts from April. So for example:

```
$startDate='2014-11-25' // Start date
$endDate ='2015-05-29'  // End date
```

Output shows only FY-14-15 , But i want FY-14-15,FY-15-16

```
function calcFY($startDate,$endDate) {

    $prefix = 'FY-';

    $ts1 = strtotime($startDate);
    $ts2 = strtotime($endDate);

    $year1 = date('Y', $ts1);
    $year2 = date('Y', $ts2);

    $month1 = date('m', $ts1);
    $month2 = date('m', $ts2);

    //get months
    $diff = (($year2 - $year1) * 12) + ($month2 - $month1);

    /**
     * if end month is greater than april, consider the next FY
     * else dont consider the next FY
     */
    $total_years = ($month2 > 4)?ceil($diff/12):floor($diff/12);

    $fy = array();

    while($total_years >= 0) {

        $prevyear = $year1 - 1;

        //We dont need 20 of 20** (like 2014)
        $fy[] = $prefix.substr($prevyear,-2).'-'.substr($year1,-2);

        $year1 += 1;

        $total_years--;
    }
    /**
     * If start month is greater than or equal to april, 
     * remove the first element
     */
    if($month1 >= 4) {
        unset($fy[0]);
    }
    /* Concatenate the array with ',' */
    return implode(',',$fy);
}

echo calcFY('2014-11-25','2015-05-29');
```

My problem is, Missing Fiscal year FY-15-16. Also what i have tried is not a better code to get this for more number of years say startdate ='2014-11-25' and endDate ='2015-05-29',

Answer (score 0):

`$total_years` returns 1 instead of 2 - you have to adjust your calculation of `$diff`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function calcFY($startDate, $endDate) {

$prefix = 'FY-';

$ts1 = strtotime($startDate);
$ts2 = strtotime($endDate);

$year1 = date('Y', $ts1);
$year2 = date('Y', $ts2);

$month1 = date('m', $ts1);
$month2 = date('m', $ts2);

$fy = array();
$idx = 0;

if((int)$month1<4)
{
    $fy[$idx] = $prefix . substr($year1-1, -2). '-'. substr($year1, -2);
    $idx++;
}

for($i = $year1; $i<=$year2; $i++)
{
    $fy[$idx] = $prefix . substr($i, -2).'-'.substr($i+1, -2);  $idx++; 
}

return implode(',',$fy);
}
```